# Overriding nofollow rules with meta tag

Tags: seo, links, meta-tags, nofollow, dofollow

I'm using a blog that automatically nofollows links in spite of manually dofollowing links in the HTML code. so I decided to put this code:

```
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow,noodp,noydir"/>
```

in the head of the blog to enable following for my link.

My question is that will that code override each link's `rel="nofollow"` rule and let search engine crawl and count those links for SEO?

Comment: Thanks for the info, good point. (Do not assume just because you see a backlink that it’s carrying weight) wish i knew all this earlier :)

Comment: you're welcome but i think you should thank Deimoks. :)

Comment: Search engines still crawl nofollow links, they don't just give the link juice. If you don't believe me, check your server logs.

Comment: so is it even useful for PR?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Search engines crawlers follow the most restrictive rule. If you use `nofollow` in your meta tag, no link will be followed. If you use `follow` in your meta tag, all links will be followed except those with `rel="nofollow"`.

So answer to your question is **no**, meta tag with `follow` doesn't override individual `rel="nofollow"`.

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.nz/2007/03/using-robots-meta-tag.html
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/96569?hl=en

Comment: so bad, but Thanks. however, in my google webmaster, I've seen many links from sites (including stackexchange) with rel="nofollow" links to be counted as backlinks for my site. i doubt that Google is reckless about nofollow links...

Comment: Links with `rel="nofollow"` does not transfer PageRank or anchor text, so it won't help to your SEO. These are Google's Matt Cutts' words: 

_"Do not assume just because you see a backlink that it’s carrying weight. I’m going to say that again: Do not assume just because you see a backlink that it’s carrying weight. Sometime in the next year, someone will say “But I saw an insert-link-fad-here backlink show up in Google’s backlink tool, so it must count. Right?” And then I’ll point them back here, where I say do not assume just because you see a backlink that it’s carrying weight."_

Comment: well looks like Google's made it far more complicated than i thought.